# System Update Failure on Rooted Device

Tags: ota-update, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Tab M8 tablet (FHD FB-8705F) that's rooted. There is a System Update available. When I download this update I get a pop up screen to install. When I click on this the phone restarts and i see the Android Bot. On this screen it says Error and after a few moments it restart. After the restart I get a message "Failed to install ota package"

Is there a way to install the package on a rooted device without having to revert to the stock boot.img?

Comment: [FlashFire](https://flashfire.chainfire.eu) or [Magisk](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/ota.html)

Comment: After downloading the ota file to my tablet, where do I find it?

Comment: @alecxs From what I can see both options require to revert to stock boot image. I'm looking for a way to upgrade without reverting to stock.

Comment: it is done automatically, if that makes a difference for you

Comment: FlashFire is reporting that it doesn't support 20.4 Magisk. Is there a way around this? Or can I install an older version that will let it work.